# My app is not able to auto read OTP only for Redmi note 5 pro phones

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am using Red-mi note 5 pro MIUI version 11.0.3 i am using with Auto Read otp from Firebase but that otp is not entering automatically in my mobile. 
But its automatic getting every android mobile also even in MIUI versions 11.0.2,11.0.4,11.0.8
 ( Samsung,one plus, etc..)

Please help me to find out the solution for this problem.

```
private void signInWithCredential(PhoneAuthCredential credential) {
    Log.d("getsms","sign credential");

    firebaseAuth.signInWithCredential(credential)
            .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                    Log.d("getsms", "completed0");
                    System.out.println("otpmobilenumber  " + mobilenumber);
                    final FirebaseUser user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();

                    Const.UUID = user.getUid();
                    Log.d("UUIdd  ", "uid no" + Const.UUID);
                    if (user.getUid() == null) {
                        Log.d("currentuid  ", "failure");
                        Log.d("getsms", "uid no null");
                    } else if (user.getUid() != null) {
                        Log.d("getsms", "uid no" + Const.UUID);
                        Log.d("getsms", "userexists" + Const.UserExists);
                        callIntent();

                    }


                }

            });
}
private void sendVerificationCode(String phonenumber) {
    Log.d("getsms","phoneNumber "+phonenumber);
    PhoneAuthProvider.getInstance().verifyPhoneNumber(
            phonenumber,
            60,
            TimeUnit.SECONDS,
            OtpActivity.this,
            new PhoneAuthProvider.OnVerificationStateChangedCallbacks() {
                @Override
                public void onVerificationCompleted(@NonNull PhoneAuthCredential phoneAuthCredential) {
                    Log.d("getsms","code "+phoneAuthCredential.getSmsCode());
                    mobileotp=phoneAuthCredential.getSmsCode();
                    mobileotp = phoneAuthCredential.getSmsCode();
                    if (mobileotp != null) {
                        char[] chars = mobileotp.toCharArray();
                        System.out.println("charrrsss" + chars);
                        String c1 = String.valueOf(mobileotp.charAt(0));
                        String c2 = String.valueOf(mobileotp.charAt(1));
                        String c3 = String.valueOf(mobileotp.charAt(2));
                        String c4 = String.valueOf(mobileotp.charAt(3));
                        String c5 = String.valueOf(mobileotp.charAt(4));
                        String c6 = String.valueOf(mobileotp.charAt(5));

                        one.setText(c1);
                        two.setText(c2);
                        three.setText(c3);
                        four.setText(c4);
                        five.setText(c5);
                        six.setText(c6);
                        otpcode.setText(mobileotp);
                       /* otpcode.setOnCompleteListener(new com.broooapps.otpedittext2.OnCompleteListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onComplete(String value) {
                                otpcode.setText(value);
                            }
                        });*/
                        Log.d("getsms", "call verifyCode");
                        verifyCode(mobileotp);
                        //otpcode.setText(mobileotp);
                    } else {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Enter The Otp",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        //otpcode.setError("Enter The OTP");
                    }

                }
                @Override
                public void onVerificationFailed(@NonNull FirebaseException e) {
                    Log.d("getsms","code fail "+e.getMessage());
                }

                @Override
                public void onCodeSent(@NonNull String s, @NonNull PhoneAuthProvider.ForceResendingToken forceResendingToken) {
                    super.onCodeSent(s, forceResendingToken);
                    verificationid=s;
                    Log.d("getsms","verify code "+s);
                }
            }
    );
}
```

Comment: Is it for SMS verification?

Comment: yes is it otp SMS verification